# Functions turning noexcept in C++17?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, noexcept, exception-specification

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38763375/3919155), exception specifications will become part of the function type in C++17. Does this mean that exception specifications for many functions will also change, e.g. functions in the C compatibility headers getting `noexcept` specifications? **Which standard functions will have their exception specifications changed to `noexcept` in C++17?**

**EDIT:** Apparently [P0488R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0488r0.pdf), the 2016-10-19 National Body Comments on the standard working draft, includes proposed changes to mark several C compatibility functions `noexcept` (see US 172-178). I guess we'll have to wait for a reaction from the WG21 on these.

Comment: The proposal says that exception specification will become part of the function type, but nothing about changing the standard library.

Comment: @Gonmator It just seems awkward if stuff like `std::sqrt` would not become `noexcept` as a natural consequence to this change in the type system.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30225086/1938163

Comment: @jotik: "*as a natural consequence to this change in the type system.*" Why would that be "a natural consequence" of this change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++17 change to `noexcept` is permitting function pointers to have the `noexcept` type.

C++17 change to `noexcept` has nothing to do with what functions in the standard library are marked `noexcept`.

Neither depends on the other.

I am aware of no changes in C++17 to mark every function from the C library `noexcept`.