# Combining std::unique_ptr and named constructors

Tags: c++, option-type, unique-ptr, named-constructor

So I am pretty new to C++ and I'm trying to combine `std::unique_ptr` with a named constructor returning a `std::optional`. I've got the following structure:

```cpp
class AbstractClass {
public:
    virtual ~AbstractClass() {}
};

class ChildClassA : public AbstractClass {
public:
    static std::optional<ChildClassA> construct(...) { ... }

private:
    ChildClassA(...) : ...{...} { ... }
};

std::unique_ptr<AbstractClass> construct(...) {
    if (...) {
        return std::make_unique<ChildClassA>(...); // call ChildClassA::construct(...) here
    } else {
        return std::make_unique<ChildClassB>(...); // call ChildClassB::construct(...) here
    }
}
```

I want to have a function `construct()` that calls the constructor of one of the child classes depending on some value. The constructors of these child classes may fail, thus I am using named constructors returning an `std::optional` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989807/how-to-handle-failure-in-constructor-in-c). `construct()` should return a `std::unique_ptr` to make passing of ownership explicit and prevent copying of the constructed object.

Is this possible?

Comment: Only if your child classes are movable

Comment: Much simpler to change your factory functions to return null `unique_ptr`s instead of `std::optional`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your classes are movable then you can move them into the `unique_ptr`:

```
#include <optional>
#include <memory>

class AbstractClass {
public:
    virtual ~AbstractClass() {}
};

class ChildClassA : public AbstractClass {
public:
    static std::optional<ChildClassA> construct();

private:
    ChildClassA(){}
};

class ChildClassB : public AbstractClass {
public:
    static std::optional<ChildClassB> construct();

private:
    ChildClassB(){}
};

std::unique_ptr<AbstractClass> construct(bool a) {
    if (a) {
        auto temp = ChildClassA::construct();
        if (temp) {
            return std::make_unique<ChildClassA>(std::move(*temp));
        }
        return {};
    } else {
        auto temp = ChildClassB::construct();
        if (temp) {
            return std::make_unique<ChildClassB>(std::move(*temp));
        }
        return {};
    }
}
```

However a possibly null `unique_ptr` would be much simpler for this usecase:

```
#include <optional>
#include <memory>

class AbstractClass {
public:
    virtual ~AbstractClass() {}
};

class ChildClassA : public AbstractClass {
public:
    static std::unique_ptr<ChildClassA> construct();

private:
    ChildClassA(){}
};

class ChildClassB : public AbstractClass {
public:
    static std::unique_ptr<ChildClassB> construct();

private:
    ChildClassB(){}
};

std::unique_ptr<AbstractClass> construct(bool a) {
    if (a) {
        return ChildClassA::construct();
    } else {
        return ChildClassB::construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd extract the `optional` -> `unique_ptr` thing into its own function (possibly with a `Args&& ... args` + forwarding incantation) to improve this answer (e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/Y2xcF7) but overall this is also the solution I would recommend under these constraints.